# Ionic Collection-repeat orderBy issue

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm writing an app using the Ionic framework that has a list of items (collection-repeat) ordered by a state ("Checked" or "Not checked"). This state can be changed dynamically by the user.
Using the last stable version of Ionic (1.0.1 - Vanadium Vaquita (2015-06-30)), when a user click on an item, the order of the items gets incorrect (not ordered by "checked" items).

Here is a codepen example (just click around on some item and see that the order of the items will be incorrect): 
    http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXOGye

(Some Code:
`collection-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'check'" ng-click="checkItem(item)" ng-class="{'item-light' : item.check !== 'C', 'item-calm': item.check === 'C'}">`)

If i use the nightly build of ionic (commented on the codepen), the order of the items will be incorrect only (for what i've tested) if i click on the last item.

Can anyone tell me if i'm doing something wrong or is there some workaround for this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please give more details about what you actually want to do?

Answer (score 0):

correct me if im wrong but I'm guessing you just want all the checked items to show before the unchecked. Personally i would use ng-repeat over collection-repeat going by previous experience. I have always had problems with dynamic actions with collection repeat lists if you are worried about the memory problem you can uses ionic infinite scroll so all the items aren't being loaded in at once.

Heres a working forked example of your codepen:
http://codepen.io/aidan2129/pen/WryQxa

```
<ion-item class="item-icon-left" item-height="52" item-width="'95%'" ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'check'" ng click="checkItem(item)" ng-class="{'item-light' : item.check !== 'C', 'item-calm': item.check === 'C'}">
```

Ionic infinite scroll documentation:
http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionInfiniteScroll/

I hope this helps couldn't fully understand your question but i can't think of any reason to use collection-repeat as i've never experienced problems with ng-repeat.